# Proof of $ (n-1 \mp 1) \ \sum_{i=1}^n\ \vert z_i \vert^2 \pm \vert \sum_{j=1}^n z_j \vert^2 = \sum_{1\le k\lt l\le n}\vert z_k \pm z_l \vert^2 $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm studying for the exam and I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time if anyone could help me solve it, it would be great.
(This problem is not being graded it's one of the problems for practice
at the end of the chapter.)

Prove that
$$ (n-1 \mp 1) \ \sum_{i=1}^n\ \vert z_i \vert^2  \pm \vert \sum_{j=1}^n z_j \vert^2 = \sum_{1\le k\lt l\le n}\vert z_k \pm z_l \vert^2 $$ (z is complex number).

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please check the problem statement. The two sides of the identity have different degrees of homogeneity (quadratic on the left, linear on the right), so this cannot be correct.

Comment: For $n=2$, $z_1=2$, $z_2=2$, with minus, plus, plus: $(2-1-2)(4+4)+(4+4)=0$ on the left-hand side, $4$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks, I wrote it wrong, there should be a square on the right side. I corrected it.